# Section 4.3 Page 26 in Loring Tu's Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

On Section 4.3, Page 26 in Loring Tu's *Differential Geometry*:
[image]

The underlined part is what I cannot understand. Why is $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ in general not defined? What does "a canonical frame of vector fields" exactly mean?

I got confused at this point, and I hope someone could explain it explicitly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame field is a collection of vector fields that form a basis of the tangent space at every point of your manifold. These need not exist for an arbitrary manifold. So, you may not be able to represent $V$ as given, hence, you may not be able to define the derivative in that manner, either.

A smooth vector bundle has a smooth frame if and only if the vector bundle is trivial. Here is another useful situation, where you can get an orthonormal one (summary: on a surface with a Riemannian metric, you get it iff the surface is orientable and admits a nowhere vanishing vector field): [Existence of orthonormal frame](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216299/existence-of-orthonormal-frame).

Comment: Hello, I know almost three years have passed but I had a doubt about the answer: when I consider a point p of an arbitrary manifold M, and a chart $(U,x_1, ...,, x_n)$ around that point, I should be able to express a vector of the tangent space $T_pM$ as $\sum v_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p$ and if by varying the point p considered I should obtain an expression of a vector field expanded in the basis of the partial derivatives, so why can't I take as a smooth frame on M the partial derivative (with respect to the coordinates of the charts)?